# Spring Boot (5) JPA : Column name annotation fails (with set naming convention)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa

I am having an issue where columns are getting renamed to snakecase. Sadly I can not rename the columns since I am creating a 3rd party tool to work on software developed for us by another company. I have googled / searched SO and tried all sorts of fixes. I am a noob at spring / JPA/ hibernate and some help would be greatly appreciated. Using IntelliJ Ultimate if that matters.

Edit:
Might help if I include the error I am getting.

`Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'birth_date'.`

Entity

```
package net.glmhc.dmhwebservices.entities;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Clients")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONE)
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = "Client.findById", query = "SELECT c FROM Clients c WHERE c.id = :id")
,@NamedQuery(name = "findGenderById", query = "SELECT c FROM Codes c WHERE c.id = :id")})
public class Clients{

    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "char(36)")
    private String id;

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name = "CreateUser", columnDefinition = "char(36)")
    private String createUser;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "CreateDate")
    private LocalDateTime createDate;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "UpdateUser", columnDefinition = "char(36)")
    private String updateUser;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "UpdateDate")
    private LocalDateTime updateDate;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = false)
    private final Set<ClientNames> clientNames = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = false)
    private final Set<ClientAddresses> clientAddresses = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = false)
    private final Set<ClientEmails> clientEmails = new HashSet<>();

    @Column(name = "ClientCode")
    private String clientCode;

    @Column(name = "AlternateClientCode")
    private String alternateClientCode;

    @Column(name = "BirthDate")
    private LocalDate birthDate;

    public Clients(String id, String createUser, LocalDateTime createDate, String updateUser, LocalDateTime updateDate, String clientCode, String alternateClientCode, LocalDate birthDate, boolean declinedEthnicity, boolean declinedLanguage, boolean declinedRace, String mpi, String preferredName, String ssn, Codes genderCodes, String rcopiaId, boolean memoHasHighImportance, String memo, String profileImageId, boolean confidentialClient, String maritalStatus, String stateReportingEthnicity, String veteranStatus, String legalStatus, String employmentStatus, String livingArrangement, String incomeSource, LocalDate livingArrangementLastChanged, Integer grossMonthlyIncome, Integer householdSize, String appUser, Long mendWardId, String genderIdentity, String religiousPreference, String sexualOrientation, String genderAtBirth, String preferredPronouns, String uniqueStateIdentifier) {
        this.id = id;
        this.createUser = createUser;
        this.createDate = createDate;
        this.updateUser = updateUser;
        this.updateDate = updateDate;
        this.clientCode = clientCode;
        this.alternateClientCode = alternateClientCode;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
      
    }

    public Clients() {

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Clients{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", createUser='" + createUser + '\'' +
                ", createDate=" + createDate +
                ", updateUser='" + updateUser + '\'' +
                ", updateDate=" + updateDate +
                ", clientNames=" + clientNames +
                ", clientAddresses=" + clientAddresses +
                ", clientEmails=" + clientEmails +
                ", clientCode='" + clientCode + '\'' +
                ", alternateClientCode='" + alternateClientCode + '\'' +
                ", birthDate=" + birthDate +
     
                '}';
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCreateUser() {
        return createUser;
    }

    public void setCreateUser(String createUser) {
        this.createUser = createUser;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(LocalDateTime createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }

    public String getUpdateUser() {
        return updateUser;
    }

    public void setUpdateUser(String updateUser) {
        this.updateUser = updateUser;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getUpdateDate() {
        return updateDate;
    }

    public void setUpdateDate(LocalDateTime updateDate) {
        this.updateDate = updateDate;
    }

    public Codes getGenderCodes() {
        return genderCodes;
    }

    public void setGenderCodes(Codes genderCodes) {
        this.genderCodes = genderCodes;
    }

    public Set<ClientNames> getClientNames() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(clientNames);
    }


    public Optional<ClientNames> getConfidentialName() {
        return clientNames.stream().filter(ClientNames::getConfidentialClient).findFirst();
    }

    public Optional<ClientNames> getNonAliasName() {
        return clientNames.stream().filter(clientNames -> !clientNames.getAlias()).findFirst();
    }

    public Set<ClientAddresses> getClientAddresses() {return Collections.unmodifiableSet(clientAddresses);}

    public Set<ClientEmails> getClientEmails() { return Collections.unmodifiableSet(clientEmails); }

    public String getClientCode() {
        return clientCode;
    }

    public void setClientCode(String clientCode) {
        this.clientCode = clientCode;
    }

    public String getAlternateClientCode() {
        return alternateClientCode;
    }

    public void setAlternateClientCode(String alternateClientCode) {
        this.alternateClientCode = alternateClientCode;
    }

    public LocalDate getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(LocalDate birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    }
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
    properties:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/;databaseName:DBNAME
    username: sa
    password:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the context of my application was being bypassed as I was not using all of spring boot and partially creating my own context. Rebuilding the context to work more in line with spring boot made it pick up the proper configuration from applicatiom.yml.

Answer (score 0):

You have configured the physical naming strategy to use **org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl** which by implementation should return the Identifier name as set ( which is what you want).
Maybe you also have to configure the implicit naming strategy for the case you have some fields where you didn't set the column name explicitely.

Your application.yml file could look like this (i removed the properties field from it since you didn't used it):

```
 spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
        implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/;databaseName:DBNAME
    username: sa
    password:
```

If none of the strategies works for you, you can always write your own by implementing the interfaces *org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy* (for physical naming) and org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategy (for implicit naming).

Comment: Yes I had tried having the implicit-strategy in there as well and it did not work. Worse part is I remember finding a fix for this at some point but I can't remember what it was now but it has been months.

Comment: I am starting to wonder if my applications.yml is being ignored all together but it looks like Intellij is seeing it as a configuration file so I am not sure.